# How to reference the current or main activity from another class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I often find myself needing to access methods that require referencing some activity. For example, to use `getWindowManager`, I need to access some Activity. But often my code for using these methods is in some other class that has no reference to an activity. Up until now, I've either stored a reference to the main activity or passed the context of some activity to the class. Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: +1 This is a great question! This is a problem that lots of developers have: How do I figure out what the currently running (or "top") Activity is?

Comment: My personal opinion is that it sucks that Google hasn't made a simple API method to access the currently active activity regardless where you are in code. After all, Android knows what it is and keeps track of it. Why not be nice to the rest of us poor boys and let us in on it :-(

Comment: if you need some methods through out of all of your activities which do simply the same, wouldn't it be better to create an abstract class which implements all these methods and let your activities derive from it? or do I get you wrong?

Comment: herom, you shouldn't have to bother creating anything. If Android knows what the current activity is, it should make a reference to it easily available.

Comment: sorry for the (maybe stupid) question, but I can't think of a situation where I would need this. could you give me a hint, or describe a situation of yours where you need this (just for clearing things, so I can understand what you want to do)? thanks in advance!

Comment: Please @AndroidDev mark my answer as the correct answer

Comment: @herom , it is required to access the currently active context so that you can do some processing or calculation based on the currently displaying context.

Answer (score 27):

If you already have a valid context, just use this:
`Activity activity = (Activity) context;`

Comment: Unless the context happens to be the application, in which case that will cause a ClassCastException.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't always work, you have to be sure that what you are casting is effectively an Activity or you'll have a ClassCastException. To do that you can do "if(context instanceOf Activity){ // proceed to cast }"

Comment: @AleMuzzi   you saved my time .Thanks +1  vote for u

Comment: @AndroidDev please consider mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 17):

Passing context is better way for refrence Activity.

You can pass Context to another class.

**IN Activity ::**

```
AnotherClass Obj  = new AnotherClass(this);
```

**IN Another Class**

```
class AnotherClass{

public AnotherClass(Context Context){

    }

}
```

Comment: But if there are several activities loaded only one of them will be active at any moment, so I suspect that there is a method to access whatever the current activity is without having to pass around a context.

Comment: Please explain why is this a better way?

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the necessary methods in your activity and implement a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Then, simply pass a handler instance to your classes, where you can obtain a message for handler and send it to target.

Comment: If I'm going to do that, I might just as well pass the context of the activity to the class.

Answer (score 4):

You can make you application instance a singleton, and use it when you need a Context

An example is in this question:
[Android Application as Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178245/android-application-as-singleton)

This way, when you need a Context, you can get it with
`Context context = MyApplication.getInstance()`

This might not be the cleanest solution, but it has worked well for me so far

Comment: Would never work if I was writing the classes and gave them to someone else who could not use a Singleton.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to android so my suggestion may look guffy but what if you'll just create a reference to your activity as private property and assign that in `OnCreate` method? You can even create your CustomActivity with OnCreate like that and derive all your activities from your CustomActivity, not the generic Activity provided by android.

```
class blah extends Activity{
  private Activity activityReference;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityReference = this;
    }

}
```

after that you could use that the way you want, i.e. in

```
Intent i = new Intent(activityReference, SomeOtherActivity.class)
```

etc

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to get the Activity to a non-activity class that I have not seen discussed in forums. This was after numerous failed attempts at using getApplicationContext() and of passing the context in as a parameter to constructors, none of which gave Activity. I saw that my adapters were casting the incoming context to Activity so I made the same cast to my non-activity class constructors:

```
public class HandleDropdown extends Application{
...
    public Activity activity;
...
public HandleDropdown() {
    super();
}
public HandleDropdown(Activity context) {
    this.activity = context;
    this.context = context;
}
public void DropList(View v,Activity context) {
    this.activity = context;
    this.context = context; 
...
}
```

After doing this cast conversion of Context to Activity I could use this.activity wherever I needed an Activity context.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways for Activities communication.

you can use:

- the startActivityForResult method
- a system of broadcast message and receiver (you can broadcast an event from the actual activity, and register a receiver in the target activity. Remember that the target activity must be previously initialized and non finished)
- as you say, store a reference of the target activity wherever you need.

Answer (score 2):

We built a framework for this. We have a `BaseActivity` class that inherits from `Activity` and it overrides all the lifecycle methods and has some static (class) variables that keep track of the activity stack. If anything wants to know what the current activity is, it just calls a static method in `BaseActivity` that returns the activity on top of our privately-managed stack.

It is kinda hacky, but it works. I'm not sure I would recommend it though.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Activity getLaunchActivity()
{
    final Class<?> activityThreadClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");

    final Method methodApp = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentApplication");
    Application App = (Application) methodApp.invoke(null, (Object[]) null);
    Intent launcherIntent = App.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(App.getPackageName());
    ActivityInfo launchActivityInfo = launcherIntent.resolveActivityInfo(App.getPackageManager(), 0);
    Class<?> clazz;
    try
    {
        clazz = Class.forName(launchActivityInfo.name);
        if(clazz != null)
            return Activity.class.cast(clazz.newInstance());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the Intent in the class you want to do these methods, and send your information to it in a Bundle like so:

```
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.my.pkg","com.my.pkg.myActivity"));
    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    i.putExtras(data);

    startActivityForResult(i);
```

Then use an OnActivityResultListener to grab the new data.

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for. All I want is a reference to whatever the current activity is, or the main one. You can have a class call a class and go quite deep. There should not be a need to pass a context to each class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a singleton class has an instance of the class below as a member.

```
public class InterActivityReferrer <T> {
    HashMap<Integer, T> map;
    ArrayList<Integer> reserve;

    public InterActivityReferrer() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        reserve = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public synchronized int attach(T obj) {
        int id;
        if (reserve.isEmpty()) {
            id = reserve.size();
        }
        else {
            id = reserve.remove(reserve.size() - 1);
        }

        map.put(id, obj);
        return id;
    }

    public synchronized T get(int id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }

    public synchronized T detach(int id) {
        T obj = map.remove(id);
        if (obj != null) reserve.add(id);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

This class can get a T object and return a unique integer assigned to the object by attach(). Assigned integers will not collide with each other unless HashMap fails. Each assigned integer will be freed when its corresponding object is detached by detach(). Freed integers will be reused when a new object is attached.

And from a singleton class:

```
public class SomeSingleton {
    ...
    private InterActivityReferrer<Activity> referrer = new InterActivityReferrer<>();
    ...
    public InterActivityReferrer<Activity> getReferrer() {return referrer;}
}
```

And from an activity that needs to be referred:

```
    ...
    int activityID = SomeSingleton.getInstance().getReferrer().attach(this);
    ...
```

Now with this, a unique integer corresponding to this activity instance is returned. And an integer can be delivered into another starting activity by using Intent and putExtra().

```
    ...
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("thisActivityID", activityID);
    startActivityForResult(i, SOME_INTEGER);
    ...
```

And from the another activity:

```
    ...
    id refereeID = getIntent().getIntExtra("thisActivityID", -1);
    Activity referredActivity = SomeSingleton.getInstance().getReferrer().get(refereeID);
    ...
```

And finally the activity can be referred. And InterActivityReferrer can be used for any other class.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Just a guess since I haven't done this but it might work.

1) Get your applicationContext by making your Android Application class a Singleton.

2) Get your ActivityManager class from the context.

3) Get a list of RunningTaskInfos using getRunningTasks() on the ActivityManager.

4) Get the first RunningTaskInfo element from the list which should be the most recent task launched.

5) Call topActivity on that RunningTaskInfo which should return you the top activity on the activity stack for that task.

Now, this seems like a LOT more work than any of the other methods mentioned here, but you can probably encapsulate this in a static class and just call it whenever. It seems like it might be the only way to get the top activity on the stack without adding references to the activities.

Comment: I didnät give you the downvote, but...one of the problems with this technique is that you need permissions to getRunningTasks() and that scares a lot of users.

Comment: @DavidWasser That is true, I don't recommend this approach, but I posted it more to show what kind of work you would need to go through to get the currently running activity off the stack without a reference.