# Can't access Application variable from OnClickListener class

Tags: java, android, variables

I have an OnCLick listener class in my Android app defined as below. I need to access an application-level variable, but the last line in this code generates this compile error:
"The method getApplication() is undefined for the type OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem"

How can I access Application variables from this class?

```
public class OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem implements OnClickListener {
    private long glbMealId = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getMealId();
```

Comment: coudl you please provide some more code?

Comment: Try with classname.this or put getContext()

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty explicit. `this` is the listener object, not the Context executing the listener.

You should use `ActivityExecutingListener.this.getApplication()`.

EDIT : If your listener is not an anonymous/inner class, you need to store the Context in the listener instance :

```
public class OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem implements OnClickListener {
  private long glbMealId;
  private Activity activity;

  public OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity; // facultative, but you may need it in onClick() ...
    this.glbMealId = ((MyApplication) activity.getApplication()).getMealId();
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: I just tried your exact code but the last line gives "The method getApplication() is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: edited: getApplication() is only available from Activity, not from Context.

Comment: So how can I access my Application variable from this class?? (since it is not an Activity class)

Comment: Just pass the activity to the listener with `new OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem(this)` with `this` being an activity (or a Service since `getApplication()` is also available in the `Service`class). See the edited answer.

Comment: This is what I've coded in the Activity:</br> 
    textViewItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem(this));

Comment: Then if you change Context to Activity in the listener, everything will work great.

Comment: OK I'm now passing the Activity to the listener, which has got rid of the compile error - thanks to all. I now have an NPE with a getWritableDatabase() call which was previously working fine! Will start a separate thread so that I can post the code...

Answer (score 0):

The this operator in your case references `OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem`.

Here is an example of what you're trying to do, cut-pasted from one of my projects:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    private boolean isVisible( View view )
    {
        return true; // fake 
    }

    private class OnLikeClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {
        private boolean isVisible = PageFragment.this.isVisible(); // <------
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Do whatever

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not following this! Does it contain any clues as to how I can access my Application variable from my OnClickListener class?

Comment: You're trying to access the enclosing class. I.E. the class holding your OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem. I gave an example of how to access the enclosing class.

Comment: What is your enclosing class?

Comment: Actually I don't want to access the enclosing class necessarily. I'm simply trying to access a variable defined in the MyApplication class (which has been created purely to host some "global" variables).

Comment: Is this MyApplication extending the Android Application class, and also set in the Manifest.XML, or just a generic static class?

Comment: There is no enclosing class - this class is defined in OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem.java. There is an associated, separate Activity class which assigns this listener to its TextViews, but this Activity is an entirely separate class.

Comment: Yes MyApplication extends the Android Application class, and contains only a couple of variable declarations and getters/setters for them

Comment: Then you need a reference to an Activity class that has the getApplication() method. So pass it in the constructor. Just as degand59 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Finally understood what your question is all about.

You wanna reference your implementation of the `Application` class.
So either:

1. Pass an `Activity` to the constructor of `OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem` as @pdegand59 suggested.
2. Make MyApplication a singleton, for convenience (this is what I do because I don't like passing Activities): [Android Application as Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178245/android-application-as-singleton)