# ClassCastException: Application object is not my custom application object

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Often in Android code we use this pattern of storing data in the Application object and then accessing it via casting as such:

```
((MyApplicationObject)getApplication()).getDaggerComponent()
```

`getApplication()` should always be `MyApplicationObject` because I have specified it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. However, when you deploy this code, sometimes it causes a `ClassCastException` and we get a different object instead.

How can this be?

What is the correct workaround for this issue?

Comment: it caused class cast exception? What was the error message. It should say something like "XX cannot be cast to MyApplicationObject". What was XX in your case?

Comment: I do not know what XX is because I can only find this error in the Google Play Console, which doesn't give that information

Comment: Hm that is weird, it should not be a different Application than the one you have defined.. Anyhow the workaround would be an `instanceof` check before casting

Comment: good idea Viacheslav, for that to work this code would need to initialize crashlytics in the case that the code does not get MyApplicationObject

Comment: Are you seeing this in particular versions of the Android SDK, say API 24-25? [There's a known issue about trying to cast the Application.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137009)

Comment: Thank you for that link! 98% of the crashes are from Android 7.0, with 0.2% from Android 7.1. In the link a @google engineer says they improved things in major issues in 7.0, but didn't completely fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved in the comments: this is an Android bug, not one related to Dagger.

> Thank you for that link! **98% of the crashes are from Android 7.0, with 0.2% from Android 7.1.** In the link a @google engineer says they improved things in major issues in 7.0, but didn't completely fix it. – [gregm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108495/gregm)

See this public Google IssueTracker link, [#37137009: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast android.app.Application to com.xxx.xxApplication](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137009) (ctate's comment in [#17](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137009#comment17)):

> Yes, this is a known issue; and was largely addressed in 7.1.  There are still some edge cases in 7.1 that can result in similar circumstances -- as you can see from your analytics -- but the window of opportunity is much narrower, and Android 8 addressed those as well.

Unfortunately, for the time being, there doesn't seem to be much of an explanation or official workaround, but at least the issue is predominantly limited in scope to Android 7.0.