# How to change the ListView Daynamically from a separate class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am receiving data from network in a separate thread (which is in some other class, here the whole problem is, but I **can't** put the receiving code in activity class due to **inherent complexity of the legacy code**) and I want to update the ListView as the data is received (realtime).. For that I have created a ListView, ArratAdapter and an ArrayList variavles... Following is the some relevant code

```
public class LogInSuccessActivity extends Activity {
    private String LOG_TAG = "LogInSuccessActivity";
    private TextView welcomeTxtLbl = null;
    private ListView buddyListView = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<Buddy> buddyListAdapter = null;
    // BuddyList
    private ArrayList<Buddy> buddyList = null;


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginsuccess);
        // get the TextView and ListView
        welcomeTxtLbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginsuceeslbl);
        buddyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.buddylistview);

        String uname = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        if (uname != null) {
            welcomeTxtLbl.setText("Welcome " + uname + ", Greetings!!");
        } else {
            welcomeTxtLbl.setText("SignIn successfull !!");
        }
        buddyList = new ArrayList<Buddy>();
        buddyListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Buddy>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, buddyList);
        buddyListView.setAdapter(buddyListAdapter);

        // persist the context
        ReceiverThread.loginSuccessActi = LogInSuccessActivity.this;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onResume()
     * 
     * @Override protected void onStart() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     * super.onStart();
     * 
     * }
     */

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStop is called ");
        buddyListAdapter.clear();
        buddyList.clear();

    }

    public void addBuddy(Buddy buddy) {
        buddyList.add(buddy);
        buddyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    Runnable updateTheListView = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // synchronized (buddyList) {
            buddyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // }
        }
    };

    public void refreshTheListView(Buddy buddy) {
        System.out.println("Refreshing the ListView list size is : "
                + buddyList.size());
        buddyList.add(buddy);
        // buddyListAdapter.add(buddy);
        // buddyListView.post(updateTheListView);
        this.runOnUiThread(updateTheListView);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onDestroy()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy is called ");
        super.onDestroy();
        buddyList = null;
        buddyListAdapter = null;
        buddyListView = null;
        ReceiverThread.loginSuccessActi = null;
    }

}
```

Now from the thread I call the method `addBuddy()` whenever new Buddy  is received...Which is a static method since Receiver Thread is in a different class...

The code however is not working, Please give me suggestions to improve this code. I know its not good but I dont know how to fix it due to my lack of knowledge in andoid prorgamming. I also read somewhere about `DataSetObserver` can they be used in my case.. I am a newbie in android arena so please excuse me for my lack of basic concepts.... Thanks,

**EDIT**
One thing I forgot to mention is that I am not updating the UI from a separate thread (I know I can't), What I do is whenever Somedata (for simplicity of the question of course I do all the filtering ) arrives I call the addBuddy()...

Now on the UI thread I will call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the ArrayAdapter to carry on the view updation.

**EDIT 2**
Following is the code in another thread from where I receive data..

```
    if (loginSuccessActi != null) {
                        loginSuccessActi.refreshTheListView(new Buddy(values));
//                      loginSuccessActi.addBuddy(new Buddy(values));
                    }
```

and I get following error 
**The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.**

Comment: I think you will need to show more of your code in order to get a more specific diagnosis of your problem. Can you at least show the code that accepts new data and calls `addBuddy`.

Comment: please see the edit, I have changed the code....

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) on the android developer site.

Even though you are doing the work on a separate thread, you can't access the UI thread from another process.

One way around this would be to implement an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do the work and then update your adapter via the `onPostExecute` method.

Answer (score 0):

After reading almost all the similar questions on SO, I finally solved it by using following steps:-

1. Fixed the few design issues in the thread which was calling the addBuddy() method,
2. Changed my addBuddy method to

   public void addBuddy(final Buddy buddy) {

   ```
       Log.i(LOG_TAG, " ADDING BUDDY + " + buddy);
       buddyListView.post(// UI thread ;
               new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       synchronized (buddyList) {
                           buddyList.add(buddy);
                           buddyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       }
                       // buddyListAdapter.add(buddy);
                   }
               });
   }
   ```

I have also changed the OverAll design of the application , as I got wiser while searching the answer of this problem. Now I share data using Singelton Class and Static variables. Following links can be useful if someone else has similar problem in future.

[Painless Threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android)

[Singleton Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android)

[Using Threads](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog)

For those, who have similar problem best advice is to **"Trust Yourself, You can do it."**