# Android: How to create application class object in BaseAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am developing an Android application and maintaining Global Variables in an Application Class `MyAppData`. Now in order to use those global variables, I am creating the `MyAppData` object in my Activity as follows:

```
MyAppData mad;
mad = (MyAppData)getApplication();
```

As my activity have a custom Listview, I am using BaseAdapter to populate the LstView. Now i need to use the global variables in my BaseAdapter class. The following code doesnt allowing me to create an object of `MyAppData` class :

```
public class AlbumList_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context context;
MyAppData mad;

      public AlbumList_Adapter(Context context){
      this.context = context
      mad = (MyAppData)getApplication();
      }
}
```

Even I had tried `mad = (MyAppData)context;` but no Luck. I dont know where I have mistaken.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android/3827166#3827166

Comment: What kind of global variables are there? This is probably a bad design.

Comment: And additionally with your code you're not *creating* object, you're getting object.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. Singleton and Application class both have their advantages and disadvantages. I preferred Application class because whenever I start my application, im getting startup data from shared preferences through Appication class as the appication class runs first when an app is opened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

 private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  mInstance = this;
}

public static MyApplication getInstance() { return mInstance; }

}
```

Then you can use `MyApplication.getInstance()` throughout your code.