# Android Running one application multiple times

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how to allow a user to run my application more than one time.  It is a script that runs in the background and I would like the user to be able to run it as many times as they want i.e. multiple instances.  Which launch mode would best accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Android Services are singletons](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/4_EJTGYhAxU), so you cannot have more than one.
Applications are also singletons, and [there is quite a discussion on this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android).

The best way to implement what you are looking for would be to run your script/background process in a thread, and allow your Service or Application to spawn an indefinite number of these threads.

Comment: Im using pythong and SL4A for my scripting so Id have to see how/if thats possible.  Not an expert at this at all.