# Getting output from second activity class to first activity which is invokes by the first activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My code has two activities.

```
public class OnCallingActivity extends Activity implement TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{}

public class TextReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver{}
```

i want first activity to extend sencond activity

```
OnCallingActivity extends TextReceiverActivity {}
```

so I did this,

```
public class OnCallingActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

  private TextReceiverActivity TextReceiverActivityClass;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.on_calling_layout);

    TextReceiverActivityClass= new TextReceiverActivity();
    speaker= new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    callerIdText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callerIdtextview);
    callerText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callermsgtextview);
    translatedText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.translatedTextview);
    speakButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    sendButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsend);
    endCallButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonendCall);        
}
```

my second activity is as follow,

```
public class TextReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     number ="";
     message="";

     final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 

     try {
        if(bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pduObjects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for(int i = 0; i < pduObjects.length; ++i) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduObjects[i]);

                number = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Toast.makeText(context, "SENDER NUMBER: " + number + "; MESSAGE: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }               
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

in first activity i called the method of second activity like this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

    TextReceiverActivityClass.onReceive(context, intent);       

}
```

**onReceive gives values for number and message..so how can i get them to my first activity to display them in TextViews.**

onReceive is an inbuilt method so i can't change the return type.

Comment: Please properly format your question. This is unreadable.

Comment: sorry..Just did it ,

Answer (score 0):

1. If `TextReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver`, then TextReceiverActivity isnt an Activity and I would refrain from calling it an Activity.
2. The `onReceive` method of a BroadcastReceiver is meant to be called from the Android sytem, not you.
3. To send a message from an Activity to a BroadcastReceiver you would send a Broadcast. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).
4. If you want to send a message from your BroadcastReceiver to your Activity, there's a [couple](https://trinitytuts.com/pass-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-activity-without-reopening-activity/) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973107/pass-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-activity) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083430/communication-between-broadcastreceiver-and-activity-android) that.

Comment: Thank you Ascorbin! Your links helps to solve my problem.