# Managing life cycle of an android application

Tags: android, service, android-intent

In my android project, I have a class which holds list of stream addresses (music)

Should i keep that class so i won't have to refill that list?

There may be many different screens (activities) that i will push them in to the screen or pull back from it.

Between these and screen changes ( destruction of activities ), the list will be lost...

Does this logic requires service to hold the list?

Comment: What doesn't work as currently implemented?

Comment: I loose the list if i put it to my main activity. (Array object) Should i put that object into a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to for this.

Normally, if you had a long running class that needed to survive throughout an Activity lifecycle, putting it in a bound service would work.  It would require you to transfer data via IPC.  In this case, it shouldn't matter.  Since you're dealing with essentially a `String` array, you can put it in the `Intent` object of the `Activity` you're about to start or in a `Bundle` which goes in to the `Intent` object.

On the creation of the Activity, simply open the `Bundle` using the `Intent#getExtras()` method and rebuild your list.  It won't take much longer to do compared to IPC with a `Service`, and it should be significantly easier to maintain.

EDIT:

One thing you can try is to override the `Application` object.  You have to specify the new entry point in the `Manifest`, but if you build the `Singleton` from the `Application` class and hold the reference there, it should stay alive as long as your app is running.  It will be destroyed when you leave though.

Comment: Using a static singleton class to hold the String array would work? Or the service or the new Activity creates a new one? (scope of the static object differs?)

Comment: It's unlikely to happen, but if Android flat out decides to destroy your Service to free up memory then you're out of luck.  It's best to remove dependencies rather than create them.

Comment: When a singleton is referenced correctly, it should never be garbage collected. So for example private static final Object instance = new Object(); should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the list in a static singleton, or in a class extending `Application`. Which in turn can be accessed from the activity classes with `getApplication()`.

When used correctly, the static singleton will function the same way as the application class, except for the fact that the singleton is accessible from everywhere, and the Application class only thru a Context.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android) a related question about what the difference between Application and singleton is.