# How to pass array of custom type from one activity to other activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

> This is how i am passing array of custom data type Items ** Items[]
>   itemsArr ** to intent

```
Intent pruchadeDetails = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PurchaseHistoryDetails.class);
pruchadeDetails.putExtra("item",itemsArr[position].getShoppingItems());
startActivityForResult(pruchadeDetails, 0);
```

> unable to retrive it using both methods

```
Item[] itemArr = (Item[])getIntent().getSerializableExtra("item"); //method 1
String json = pruchadeDetails.getStringExtra("item");//method 2
```

> any help is highly appreciated thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html In Android `Serializable` is not recommended, use `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code help you.

```
    intent.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra("ListName", ArrayList)
    Intent purchaseDetails= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PurchaseHistoryDetails.class);
    purchaseDetails.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra("items", yourArrayList);
    startActivityForResult(purchaseDetails,0);
```

Pass there Array List of your Custom Data Type.

Comment: The method putCharSequenceArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<CharSequence>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Item[])

Comment: because i am not passing an array list iam passing an array

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 intent.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra("ArrayListName", ArrayList)
Intent purchaseDetails= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.class);
purchaseDetails.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra("items", ArrayList);
startActivityForResult(purchaseDetails,0);
```

Comment: bro array list wount work coz i am passing a normal array items[]

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom item parcelable and then put the array as a Parcelable array in a Bundle, to pass it to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have look at this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Make your Model Parcelable. An example is given in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in-memory, three solutions come to my mind:

1. Make your data *parcelable* as described, e.g., by @takecare. See also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html
2. Use JSON to serialize your data. See, e.g., http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html
3. Use a singleton class as a holder for your data. You can also use the application object. See, e.g., [Singletons vs. Application Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

For First activity use below.

```
List<String> itemList = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
itemList.add("i'th List"+i);
}

Intent intent= new Intent(this,ReportsActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("items", (ArrayList<String>) itemList);
startActivity(intent);
```

And get this array to another activity using

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    List<String> itemList= bundle.getStringArrayList("items");

    for(int i=0;i<itemList.size();i++){
       Log.i("TAG", itemList.get(i));       
    }
```

Comment: Review this link.  [Pass Custom Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)