# Bitmap cache throughout the whole application

Tags: android, caching

I am trying to develop a bitmap cache for my whole application.
From what i read lru cache would be the correct choice.

My question is how can i access this cache throughout my whole app?

In the first activity i will load the bmps in the cache. I want to have access to this cache in the next activities the user will access.

I am not sure how to configure this. Do i need to create a static reference or how can i send the cache between activities? I don't have much experience in this domain so help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static reference would work, perhaps creating a Singleton class.

You could also instead extend the Application class and store references in there as the application (`Activity.getApplication()`) will be the same between activities.

You would have to put into the android manifest xml the new MyApplication class

```
    <application
    android:name="com.example.MyApplication" ...
```

Though I find creating Singletons to be the easier approach. There is a discussion of the two here [Singletons vs. Application Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android)

Comment: And a good cache library is also available: https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache

Comment: yeah cache libraries are a good way to go, here's a comparison of a few https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/bfAFC5YZ3mq - I've found UrlImageViewHelper and Picasso pretty useful in the past