# Check if Service is running from a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'll like to ask if it's possible to check a service is running from Broadcast receiver.

I know that it's possible in Activity.

Thanks for your precious help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes' it's possible to detect if service is running from anywhere you have available `Context` object:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

`MyService`  is your service class.