# Long-running process kicked off in ActivityA, need results in ActivityB

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-service

When I switch from `ActivityA`  to `ActivityB` I need to do a bit of background processing on a `Bitmap` from `ActivityA` (maybe a few seconds' worth) before it shows up in `ActivityB`. Rather than delay the launch of `ActivityB` and make my app feel sluggish I'd like to launch it immediately and have it make use of the `Bitmap` as soon as the processing is finished (the user can do useful things in `ActivityB` before the `Bitmap` is ready).

The standard answer for receiving data from long-running processes seems to be a retained, non-UI `Fragment`, which works great if your `Activity` gets destroyed then re-created, but what about where you switch to a different `Activity`? Even retained, non-UI `Fragment` instances appear to be associated with a particular `Activity` class, even after the `Activity` itself is destroyed, and it appears that calling `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag)` from an instance of `ActivityB` will fail to retrieve a retained, non-UI `Fragment` created in `ActivityA`.

Is `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag)` supposed to work from an instance of a different `Activity` and I'm just doing something wrong? Or is there some other technique recommended in this situation?

A `Service` feels like overkill here, but maybe I'm wrong and frequent creation/destruction of `Service` instances is perfectly acceptable in Android apps (in which case my question is: why bother with a retained, non-UI `Fragment` ever?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating your own Application object?

You can have a private member variable to hold your bitmap along with a getter and setter that both activities can access.

Something like:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Then reference your application in your android manifest file.

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Then in your activities, just call getApplication(), cast it to your Application class and call the getter or setter.

```
    MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
    app.setBitmap(bitmap);
    Bitmap bitmap = app.getBitmap();
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding much about recommended uses of the Application class on http://developer.android.com, but its API documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) says "There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way" - so maybe the answer is to use a singleton (then shower thoroughly).

Comment: A singleton would certainly work as well.  We all should probably shower regardless.  :)

Comment: I did a bit of searching and found an interesting discussion about singletons and `Application` that goes through a lot of the pros and cons. This comment made me feel a bit better about the API's recommendation of the singleton approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android#comment8239671_3888560

There's also a mention of Dianne Hackborn, so I tracked her down and found her preferred Singleton approach here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/2i82mjoM46M/2cqBiR9UtpYJ

Comment: Wow.  The Google group discussion is a good one complete with comments from heavy hitters like DH and Mark Murphy.  A good read!