# On back button pressed restart the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragment called `view_profile` and activity called `edit_profile`
After editing the profile if user press on back button then I want to get updated content.

Right now, on back button pressed it simply loads previous fragment without reloading the content.
How can I restart the fragment activity?

I searched on internet. I found method called `onRestart`. But, I think it's the method for activity not the fragment.

Comment: why aren't you using the principe of communicating between fragments, or a mecanism like "startActivityForResult()" between your two fragments

Answer (score 0):

You can override activity's onBackPressed() and implement your own logic there.

Answer (score -1):

In view_profile, use startActivityForResult to start edit_profile activity.
In edit_profile, handle the back button event to update the content:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch ( item.getItemId() )
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
        {
            // update the content
            this.getIntent().putExtra( "CONTENT_PARCELABLE", (Parcelable)content_data );
            this.getIntent().putExtra( "CONTENT_STRING", (String)string_content_data );
            setResult( RESULT_OK, this.getIntent() );

            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

...

in view_profile, get the updated result from data

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    boolean  have_changes = false;

    if ( requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_EDIT )
    {
        if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK )
        {
            // update the content from data
            updated_content = data.getParcelableExtra("CONTENT_PARCELABLE");
            updated_string_content = data.getStringExtra("CONTENT_STRING");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I am doing right now. It won't reload the content

Comment: I just want to recall the `onCreateView` method again

Comment: Maybe you should declare "global" variable accessible from both activities, extending Application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android/

Comment: Or consider singleton pattern - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android